# Difference between writing text/string in java file and in string.xml file in values folder of android

Tags: android

I have created a class called `Params.java` in my project where i am writing all string parameters and accessing them as static wherever they are required.

Params.java

```
public static final String USERNAME = "username";
public static final String USER_TOTAL_FOLLOWERS = "user_total_followers";
public static final String USER_EARNINGS = "user_earnings";
public static final String USER_PROFILE_PICTURE_URL = "profilepic";
```

I also have strings.xml

```
<string name="btn_txt_cancel">Cancel</string>
<string name="btn_txt_okay">Okay</string>
<string name="btn_txt_not_now">Not Now</string>
<string name="btn_txt_update">Update Now!</string>
```

To access from `Params`, i simple need to write `Params.variable_name` and form `strings.xml`, i need to write `getResources().getString(R.string.variable_name)`

I want to know

1. What is the best practice ?
2. What difference it makes in performance when accessed from these to files ?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a string in `strings.xml`, that means in current/future you can support multiple languages with the same key used in all language `strings.xml` file.

For normal constants like a key for using in bundle, better to create a class which holds all constants.

Finally the strings which are displayed in UI, the best practice is to add those in `strings.xml` and for code related usage constants use a class like `Constants.class` which holds all your constants.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So the best practice in android to store string is, Those strings are visible to user put them on string.xml file, for example hint of EditText "enter your name" and those string which are not going to visible to the user like your "Google API key" put them on Constant.java file.

This is the best practice while coding in Android.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest advantage of using `string.xml` instead of a custom file, are `translations`.

`Android Studio` provides everything you need for translating your application simply adding a new resource localized for the locale you want.

[image]

This allows you to automatically change the lenguage without coding anything except the translated text.

*(You can also buy translations from the `Google Developer Console`)*

In your code you would have to add a switch and manually manage all cases.

[More information can be found here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

**About performances**

It's pretty much the same. they both are static resources with different access ways. If there is any performance impact it would be really hard to notice it, we are talking about milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

you can use `getString(R.string.stringName);` from xml

for me i use string.xml for String Which are Visible to User. it has an Advantage when i m creating multiLanguage App.

for String that are not visible to users I prefer Params.java Like URL etc.

Answer (score 1):

To support multiple languages and to separate concerns between view and logic, use strings.xml

If it is a string that used only in code and not visible to user, use a constants class.

This way you have a more cleaner code.